# Convert String to Int in Azure data factory Derived column expression

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a dataflow task in azure data factory and used derived column transformation. One of the source derived column value is '678396' which is extracted through Substring function and datatype "String" by default. I want to convert it into "Integer" because my target column datatype is "Integer".

I've to converted the column in this expression:
ToInteger(Substring(Column_1,1,8))

Please help me with correct expression.

Kind regards,
Rakesh

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Mishra, do you have any other concerns? Please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the expression. If you column data are all like int string "678396", or the output of `Substring(Column_1,1,8)` are int String

Data Factory can convert the int string to integer data type directly from source to sink. We don't need convert again.

Make sure you set column mapping correctly in sink settings. All things would works well.

**Update:**

This my csv dataset:
[image]

You can choose the `Quote character` to singe quote, then could solve the problem. See the source data preview in Copy active and Data Flow:

Copy active source:
[image]
[image]

Data Flow overview:
[image]

In data flow, we will get the alert like you said comment, we could ignore it and debug the data flow directly:
[image]
[image]

HTH.

Comment: Hi Leon, I tried but I receievd this error when try to mapp from source to sink: "at least one incoming column is mapped to a column in the sink dataset schema with a conflicting type, which can cause NULL values or runtime errors"

Comment: Hi @RakeshMishra, please see my update, you could use Copy active directly with changing dataset settings to singe quote. If you insist to use data flow, we can ignore the alert and data flow also could works well.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you,  hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

you don't even need to substruct quotes '', as ToInteger function can convert numbers as string type